# Why is HttpContext.Session null when redirectMode = ResponseRewrite

Tags: asp.net, exception, web-config, custom-errors, redirectmode

As is suggested  [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null/343056#343056), I am using redirectMode = ResponseRewrite in my custom error configuration so my custom error page can access the exception info. This has worked like a charm for some time.

In adding some more "help the user recover from an error" type functionality, we need a piece of info that has been previously stored in Session. When implementing this, I found that the various avenues to Session end in null when redirectMode=ResponseRewrite, but they are all populated when redirectMode=ResponseRedirect (or isn't defined).

Anyone know why? It seems odd that we'd have to choose between having exception info (ResponseRewrite) or having Session (ResponseRedirect).

The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479319.aspx) on Rich Custom Error handling tells me that Session is only available when the control passing method is Server.Transfer, which is what I assumed ResponseRewrite used under the hood. Evidently that isn't the case.

Comment: Mauricio, I don't know the answer to the question yet, but to get past it, I took the redirectMode attribute out of my web config and put custom logic in the Global.asax Application_Error handler to do what I wanted.  I am replacing the exception with a "user friendly" message exception, but essentially the transfer logic is:
if(Context.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
{
   Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx");
}
Then the Error.aspx page has Page_Load code to pull the error out of context and display the message.

Comment: @Josh, that looks good, put it in an answer so I can properly upvote it :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the answer to the question yet, but to get past it, I took the redirectMode attribute out of my web config and put custom logic in the Global.asax `Application_Error` handler to do what I wanted. I am replacing the exception with a "user friendly" message exception, but essentially the transfer logic is:

`if(Context.IsCustomErrorEnabled)

{

Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx");

}`

Then the Error.aspx page has Page_Load code to pull the error out of context and display the message.