# Accessing Session in MasterPage load event after a UrlRewrite

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, url-rewriting, session-state

#### Situation:

- In Web.Config we have CustomErrors turned on with `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"`.
- In `Page_Load` of our MasterPage we access the `Session` property of the `Page`.

#### Problem:

When an Error occurs on any page the user gets redirected (via Rewrite) to our Error.aspx Page. There in the Page_Load of the MasterPage we access the Session and get an HttpException telling us to enable SessionState. But we have the SessionState enabled, definitly.

#### Question:

How can we access the session after a UrlRewrite in the Page_Load Event of our MasterPage?

Comment: what is the actual exception, or the exact message?  Also, does this happen every time an error is raised which causes the ResponseRewrite, or just at certain errors?

Comment: It happens on every uncaught Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we ended up with:

```
if( HttpContext.Current.Session != null )
{
    //Access Session here...
}
```

We can do this because the data we get from the Session is not Essential for us on the ErrorPage.

Also note that accessing `HttpContext.Current.Session` will not throw an `HttpException` whereas accessing `Page.Session` would.

Comment: This solution resolved a similar issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead...

[Why is HttpContext.Session null when redirectMode = ResponseRewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589566/why-is-httpcontext-session-null-when-redirectmode-responserewrite)

excerpt...

I don't know the answer to the question yet, but to get past it, I took the redirectMode attribute out of my web config and put custom logic in the Global.asax Application_Error handler to do what I wanted. I am replacing the exception with a "user friendly" message exception, but essentially the transfer logic is:

```
if(Context.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
{
Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx");
}
```

Then the Error.aspx page has Page_Load code to pull the error out of context and display the message.