# Session is null after ResponseRewrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, elmah

I am using the custom errors attribute in the web.config to handle custom errors

**Like this:**

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
```

After an error is thrown, the page is redirected to the error page, but when I access the session in the error page it is null.

The reason I use `ResponseRewrite` and not `ResponseRedirect` is because I pass the `Exception id` through Items using elmah.

I even tried to create new empty asp.net website and it still happens.

I've seen some similar questions but without an answer.

Comment: Could you add code or more details? I'm not reproducing the error in visual studio 2012, IIS 8.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010, iis6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced the problem, but I can't understand why this happens. In the `Application_Error` handler I can access the Session variable, but when the page loads it becomes `null`.

I found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701436/848330) that solves the problem. You need to remove the `redirectMode` from your web.config and manually do the `Server.Transfer` when you get an error. So this is the web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx"/>
```

And add this to the `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(Context.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
  {
    Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx");
  }
}
```

To specify different error pages depending on the error, you can access the error code like this:

```
HttpException httpException = (HttpException) Server.GetLastError();
int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
switch (httpCode)
{
  case 500: Server.Transfer("~/Pages/Error.aspx");break;
  case 404: Server.Transfer("~/Pages/PageNotFound.aspx");break;
  default: Server.Transfer("~/Pages/Error.aspx");break;    
}
```

Comment: Okay I did manage to make it work using your suggestion, but do you know how can I take the default redirect from the web config based on the page I'm in?

Comment: @Amir Do you want to use a different redirect for each page or do you simply want to know how to read the `defaultRedirect` property from web.config?

Comment: I know how to read the default redirect, but what happens when I want to use a different redirect?

Comment: @Amir I updated my post with some info for different redirects