# Display Exceptions in ASP.NET / Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have a custom error page in an Azure ASP.NET web app where I'd like to display

```
   <p>Oops - something went wrong.</p>
<p>The most common problem is that you tried to do something that the database enforces shouldn't happen.</p>
<p>The error is:</p>
```

In web.config I have:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" />
```

and global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
            string err = "Error Caught in Application_Error event\n" +
                    "Error in: " + Request.Url.ToString() +
                    "\nError Message:" + objErr.Message.ToString() +
                    "\nStack Trace:" + objErr.StackTrace.ToString();
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Sample_WebApp", err, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
```

**Problem: How to display the full exception on the Error.aspx page?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` attribute to the `customErrors` element if you are using ASP.NET 3.5 SP1. That should preserve the exception information stored in `Server.GetLastError()`. Then you can add a label to the `Error.aspx` page and display the exception details, i.e. `lblError.Text = Server.GetLastError().ToString()`.

Here's a similar SO question: [ASP.NET custom error page - Server.GetLastError() is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null)