# Application_Error Called but there is no Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

While debugging my MVC 4 application in VS2010 SP1, the `Application_Error()` handler was invoked but `Server.GetLastError()` was null.

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    // exception is null.  How is that possible?
}
```

[MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994a1482.aspx) `Application_Error` is

> called if an unhandled exception occurs anywhere in your ... application... You can get information about the most recent error from the `GetLastError` method.

The MSDN docs for [`Server.GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx)() states

> Return value: The previous exception that was thrown.

How can I possibly be in a state where `Application_Error()` was called but `Server.GetLastError()` returns null?

Comment: I think Application_OnError is called explicitly somewhere. So it is called albeit there is no exception. May be you can search for "Application_OnError" string in whole solution and confirm that this is not called explicitly.

Comment: @Rain: It is not called explicitly.

Comment: Please check this. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null

Comment: @Rain: The comments to the accepted answer say that the Exception was still available in Application_Error but lost by the time the error page was shown. In my case I almost always do have the Exception available. Just once, I did not and wonder why

Comment: I have recently hit this and can reproduce at will. Like the OP, I enter the Application_Error method, call Server.GetLastError. In my case I serialize the exception to session and attempt to redirect to a page which will then pull the exception out and process it correctly. Somewhere after the redirect, but before arriving at  the new page, the Application_Error method is called again. this time a call to Server.GetLastError yields a null. How can this be? I apparently have an error, but no exception. :(

Answer (score 2):

Are you using custom error handling in your web.config?  I believe that if the browser issues a redirect, the previous exception will be lost.  Take a [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null) and see if your situation is similar.

Comment: The comments to the accepted answer say that the Exception was still available in Application_Error but lost by the time the error page was shown.  In my case I almost always do have the Exception available.  Just once, I did not and wonder why.