# Where do I create error log function in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, 3-tier

I am using 3 tier architecture in asp.net, I want to put function "ErrorLog()" to log errors, where should I put in my structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Uility folder under BLL which holds common functions like CommonFunction.cs class.
In that class you can put ErrorLog , AlertMessage,Encrypt , Decrypt ... functions

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to write your Error log code in your `Global.asax` file.
It has function called `Application_Error`. This function is called automatically if an 
unhandled exception is raised.

You can create your log file there. It has `Server.GetLastError()` function that keeps the track of your last error in your project.

For more details check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null) this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to put ErrorLog() in any layer (depending on your structure, layer can be a namespace OR a project).

It should be in a Error Utility class and not in any layer, as you might want to use this to log errors from either data layer or business layer.