# Custom error page in web.config, will error info be lost?

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

If my web.config has:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="CustomErrorPage.aspx">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/CustomErrorPage.aspx?statusCode=401" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/CustomErrorPage.aspx?statusCode=403" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/CustomErrorPage.aspx?statusCode=404" />
      ...
</customErrors>
```

Now in my CustomErrorPage.aspx, how can I get the stacktrace information similar to how I see that yellow screen error page when there is no custom error page and it is outputted to the browser?

**Or, because this is redirecting to the customerrorpage.aspx, is the error essentially lost at this point and I can't access the exception information?**

This is a legacy application with complex virtual directories etc. so I can just drop one of those error libraries so easily at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's lost. You aren't even in the same request, since it's done by a redirect.

That last point is bad enough in itself (what's the point of redirecting someone to an error page?), but it affects you here. However, with `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` added to the `customErrors` element, then that solves this problem and also means that `Server.GetLastError()` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Per this SO post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null), if you are running .Net 3.5 SP1, you can use the `redirectMode` property on your `customErrors` element.

More info on the redirectMode:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.customerrorssection.redirectmode(v=vs.90).aspx

Once you do that, you'll have access to the error from Server.GetLastError():
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx

Edit:  You'd be using the `ResponseRewrite` mode for `redirectMode`

Comment: so as it stands I can't get the server.lasterror then correct?

Comment: Yeah, the way I read that is the default customError mode does a redirect, which looses that error information.

Answer (score 0):

You can log error in some file on server (you need to add Application_Error event handler in Global.asax.cs), or drop this row in webconfig to get yellow screen with exception.

Answer (score 0):

In your global.asax you can catch the error and save it to be retrieved in the Error page.

You override `Application_Error` to catch the error.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is not lost. You can call [`Server.GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx) to get the last exception thrown.

Since it returns an `Exception` object, you can simply get call `StackTrace` to get the full stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

Use GetLastError, that allows you (oddly enough) to get the last error that occurred.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx