# custom errors in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

I am trying to do an error page which redirect to it whenever an error occurs.

This is my code:

```
              <customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="On" />
```

which is working fine now how can I get the error message too on my error page

Example: Error - Index Error

Comment: I think this is a similar kind of a question [Server.GetLastError()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to get the last error that occurred (programmatically) and display it in the page. You can do that like this (in Error.aspx):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
     lblError.Text= ex.Message;
     Server.ClearError();
}
```

Where `lblError` is a Label control defined in your page just for the purpose of displaying the error messages.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Maybe useful your great article (from 2004)  in ***MSDN*** _https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479319.aspx_ and **Build a Really Useful ASP.NET Exception Engine** _ http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20030816.asp http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155810/Back-to-the-Basics-Exception-Management-Design-Gui_

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
{     
  HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

  Exception exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError ();

  string errorInfo = 
     "<br>Offending URL: " + ctx.Request.Url.ToString () +
     "<br>Source: " + exception.Source + 
     "<br>Message: " + exception.Message +
     "<br>Stack trace: " + exception.StackTrace;

  ctx.Response.Write (errorInfo);
  ctx.Server.ClearError ();

  base.OnError (e);
}
```

Read more about [ASP.NET Custom Error Pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306355)