# how to show error details with get getlasterror() object with asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i just want to show error details with getlasterror object.

here is my web config code to redirect custom error page :

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx"/>
```

and here is my Error.aspx page code to catch error :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Text;
public partial class Error : newManageClass
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadError(Server.GetLastError());
        }
    }
    protected void LoadError(Exception objError)
    {
        if (objError != null)
        {
            StringBuilder lasterror = new StringBuilder();
            if (objError.Source != null)
            {
                //lasterror.AppendLine("Source:");
                //lasterror.AppendLine(objError.Source);
                //lasterror.AppendLine();
                lbl_from_page.Text = objError.Source.ToString();
            }
            if (objError.Message != null)
            {
                //lasterror.AppendLine("Message:");
                //lasterror.AppendLine(objError.Message);
                //lasterror.AppendLine();
                lbl_errormessage.Text = objError.Message.ToString();
            }
            //if (objError.InnerException != null)
            //{
            //    lasterror.AppendLine("StackTrace:");
            //    lasterror.AppendLine(objError.StackTrace);
            //    lasterror.AppendLine();
            //    lbl_error_desc.Text = objError.InnerException.ToString();
            //}
            ViewState.Add("LastError", lasterror.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

how ever i can not get details from which page with full url and error message.

please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing a redirect, which means you are losing the context from your initial request, thus you are unable to access that exception. Add this to your `web.config` to perform a rewrite instead:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
```

Comment: how to get full url of page that was throwing error. at object.Source

Answer (score 0):

You should add attribute redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" to ensure that Server.GetLastError() will not return null.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"/>
```

Information about source page (where error occurred) can be then found in `Request.Url` in case of redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" otherwise it can be found in url parameter ?aspxerrorpath=........

More info is here [ASP.NET custom error page - Server.GetLastError() is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null)