# Server.GetLastError() returns null when Internal Server Error (500) occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, global-asax, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am making a module that logs the errors to a `.log` file and save it to the database. I am only triggering the logging under this following instances:

1. Ajax errors. More specifically, error 500 status code that has occurred on the controller.
2. When the user tries to go to a non-existent page within the web application

**The Problem:**

My 2nd goal works very well but I am having trouble with my 1st goal. The `Server.GetLastError()` returns `null` when an Internal Server error has occurred. In addition to this, it doesn't redirect the custom pages, it redirects on the `_ViewStart.cshtml` instead.

I have tried the solutions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null) but none seems to work. It still returns `null` and not the exception message. This only happens on Internal Server error (500) I think. Below is my code, the web config, and a test endpoint to simulate an error.

**Global.asax**

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        HttpException lastErrorWrapper = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;

        Exception lastError = lastErrorWrapper;
        if (lastErrorWrapper.InnerException != null)
            lastError = lastErrorWrapper.InnerException;

        string lastErrorTypeName = lastError.GetType().ToString();
        string lastErrorMessage = lastError.Message;
        string lastErrorStackTrace = lastError.StackTrace;
        
        // Creation of the log and the log file containing the error
        LogFileModel logFile = helpers.CreateLogFile(lastErrorTypeName, lastErrorMessage, lastErrorStackTrace);
        helpers.InsertActivityLog_Error(2, "", "Web portal error.", logFile.file, logFile.fileSize, logFile.fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error/ErrorHasOccured" mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound"/>
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/ErrorHasOccured"/>
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

**Test end-point on one of my Controllers**

```
public ActionResult test() {
    throw new Exception("This is a test error!");
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

If I missed something on the post I linked above, please let me know. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like ASP.Net does not allow error 500 on `Server.GetLastError()` for some reason. If somebody knows why this is the case or if I am wrong, feel free to comment here so everybody will know.

MS Docs doesn't clearly explain to me why this is the case so I made a workaround instead. I used the `object sender` parameter which holds the information I needed. I fetched the error message and the stack trace from there and passed it to my function that creates the log file to the database.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var senderValue = (HttpApplication)sender;

    string lastErrorTypeName = string.Empty;
    string lastErrorMessage = string.Empty;
    string lastErrorStackTrace = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        HttpException lastErrorWrapper = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;

        Exception lastError = lastErrorWrapper;
        if (lastErrorWrapper.InnerException != null)
            lastError = lastErrorWrapper.InnerException;

        lastErrorTypeName = lastError.GetType().ToString();
        lastErrorMessage = lastError.Message;
        lastErrorStackTrace = lastError.StackTrace;
    }
    catch (Exception) 
    {
        lastErrorTypeName = "InternalError";
        lastErrorMessage = senderValue.Context.Error.Message;
        lastErrorStackTrace = senderValue.Context.Error.StackTrace;
    }

    // Create log file and store to database
    try
    {
        LogFileModel logFile = helpers.CreateLogFile(lastErrorTypeName, lastErrorMessage, lastErrorStackTrace);
        helpers.InsertActivityLog_Error(2, "", "Web portal error.", logFile.file, logFile.fileSize, logFile.fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

I know this is not as robust as using the `Server.GetLastError()`. If you find a better solution, please feel free to answer.

Thanks!